# Can protractor be used for Test Driven Developement?

Tags: angularjs, tdd, protractor

Can protractor be used for Test Driven Developement ?
i want to know whether we can use Protractor for TDD.
If yes ,please share an example.

Comment: http://kroltech.com/2013/11/javascript-tdd-with-jasmine-and-karma/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TDD usually refers to unit testing, which can be achieved using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/). Protractor which wraps Selenium is intended for functional testing - this basically makes sure that the views on your app are working as expected. You wouldn't usually use these kind of tests to drive your development process as they can't test the actual input/output of your methods, which is what you really want to be doing in a TDD workflow.

Comment: For an application that does not have huge number of pages, protractor seems to be useless, since simply eyes are enough. TDD is by far most important since it drives your code design and enables huge refactoring without "fear".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Protractor to do the end to end testing. That complements the unit testing which is part of the TDD process.